# Sqoop - Date -timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop in the data from Oracle into Hadoop. 
In the Oracle side the date field is timestamp with format: '10/01/2015 12:00:00 AM'. How do I just put filter on month, day, and year?

Don't need hours and min in the filter, however the data that gets loaded into HDFS needs to have 10/01/2015 12:00:00 AM' format. Any idea? I looked at other stackoverflow, didn't find it this format. Thanks!!

Please see the code below. I don't get any results.

```
sqoop import \
   --compress \
   --target-dir /tmp/inbound/employee \
   --query "SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,NAME,ZIP_CODE,START_DATE FROM TEST_DB_A.EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = '12345' and ACTIVE_EMP = 'YES' and CAST(START_DATE as DATE) = '2015-10-01'  and \$CONDITIONS" \
   --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz.xyz.com:11234/TEST \
   --username 'xyz' \
   --password 'xyz' \
   --hive-drop-import-delims -m 1 \
   --fields-terminated-by , \
   --escaped-by \\ \
   --split-by EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `to_char()` function on the Oracle side:

use:

```
to_char(START_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am')
```

instead of:

```
START_DATE
```