# Sqoop Support for Oracle Date Format

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

Using Sqoop I am importing from Oracle table into hdfs and Loading to Manage Table by giving the hdfs Path Location.Below is the sqoop Command

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbcconnection \
--username user \
--password password \
--table EMPDETAILS \
--column "EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_DOB,EMP_DOJ" \
--target-dir hdfspath \
-m 1
```

This command executed successfully and when loading into hive table using hdfs location it is giving null for EMP_DOB(date type is Date)

```
create table EMP_TARGET(
   empid int,
   empname string,
   empdob date,
   empdoj timestamp) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
Location 'hdfspath';
```

When I execute the above query the `empdob` column in target hive is giving `NULL` but `empdoj` is giving Correct Value. When I checked the value in hdfs path for `empdob` it is `1980-01-01 00:00:00:0`.

Kindly help to solve the issue.

Comment: `1980-01-01 00:00:00:0` is `TIMESTAMP`. `empdob` is `date` so you'll need to remove everything after `1980-01-01`

Comment: In Oracle a `DATE` column always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components - if you insert a date without specifying the time component then Oracle will default it to midnight. If you want to store it in another language then it will probably be imported into a data type that also has all those fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45200496/1509264